# Item undefined - by page load but later by select event work without problem

Tags: vue.js

I need to set "message" on page load and later update it by select box from array in data. But by page load, the item is undefined - what make I wrong?  Thank you for advice.
the code is as well on: https://repl.it/@DaBor/find#index.html

```js
let vueApp = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selected: '1',
    options:  [  
        {id:1, projectNAME:"bobx", note:"note-bobx"},  
        {id:2, projectNAME:"danx", note:"note-danx"},  
        {id:3, projectNAME:"barb", note:"note-barb"},
        ],
    message: "start"
    
  },
 
  methods: {
    foo: function(){
    var item = this.options.find(item => item.id === this.selected);
    alert(item);
    this.message = item.note;
    },

  },
 
  mounted() {
      this.foo();
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<select v-model="selected" v-on:change="foo" >
  <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.id">
    {{ option.projectNAME }}
  </option>
</select>
<span>Selected id:{{ selected }}</span>
<br />
<span v-html="message"></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: ``selected`` in ``data`` is a ``string`` not a ``number``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `find()` callback compares `item.id` (a `Number`) to `selected` (a `String`):

```js
var item = this.options.find(item => item.id === this.selected);
                                        ^               ^
                                      Number          String
```

[*Strict equality* (`===`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) compares both type and value. Since the two types are different in this case, the comparison would always be `false`, resulting in `undefined` being returned from `find()`.

One solution is to convert `selected` to a `Number`, and use that to compare:

```js
var selectedId = Number(this.selected);
var item = this.options.find(item => item.id === selectedId);
```

[updated repl.it](https://repl.it/@tony191/find)